# Sending message from C++ to Delphi X

Tags: c++, delphi

I am trying to send a message from my C++ console app to Delphi X app on Windows 10 and it does not work for some reason. 
Below is my C++ code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    CString dataToSend = _T("MY DATA");
    COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
    cds.dwData = 1; // can be anything
    cds.cbData = sizeof(TCHAR) * (_tcslen(dataToSend) + 1);
    cds.lpData = (void*)dataToSend.GetBuffer(cds.cbData);

    HWND hwndFound;         // This is what is returned to the caller.
    hwndFound = FindWindow(_T("TMyForm"), 0);


    if (hwndFound)
    {
        printf("WINDOW IS FOUND %i... Sending a message...\n", hwndFound);
        SendMessage(hwndFound, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)hwndFound, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("WINDOW IS NOT FOUND!\n");
    }



    char* end = "";
    printf("Press enter to continue...");
    scanf(end);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my Delphi code:

```
private
    procedure WMCopyData(var Msg : TWMCopyData); message WM_COPYDATA;
....


procedure TMyForm.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
   s : AnsiString;
begin
   s := PAnsiChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData) ;
   ShowMessage(s);
end;

....

procedure TMyForm.MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   // Checking my handle
   ShowMessage(IntToStr(Handle));
end
```

C++ app says it found a handle:

WINDOW IS FOUND 3609366... Sending a message...
Press enter to continue...

Same handle is displayed when I press MyButton (3609366) but message box does not appear.
For some reason Delphi app is not receiving the message.

Do you have any idea why?

P.S.: they run under same user account.

Comment: On side notes, the Delphi code is expecting `AnsiChar` data, so you shouldn't be using `TCHAR` in the C++ code. Also, the VCL uses `WM_COPYDATA` internally, so you have to look at `dwData` before interpreting `lpData` (you should use `RegisterWindowMessage()` for the `dwData` value). And the `WPARAM` of `WM_COPYDATA` needs to be the `HWND` of the sender, not the receiver.

Comment: Useful info - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a WM_USER+1 message to Delphi, but aren't listening for that message in Delphi.

Comment: This answer no longer applies after the question was edited.

Comment: Just noticed that. Thanks!